# Visual Basic Enable Aero animations with borderless window

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, aero

Is it possible to enalbe aero animations (close and minimize) with a window that doesnt have a border (system chrome)? Im using visual basic express 2010 on windows 7

Comment: I have been trying to find the answer to this as well, not able to find it unfortunately :/